# CImg FFT return values

Tags: c++, fft, cimg

I'm a bit confused about the return values of CImg's
`get_FFT()`
Function.

The fourier transform should give me a real and imaginary part.
`get_FFT()` returns a CImgList with two images - which one is the real and which is the imaginary part? 
It seems that there's no clue in the documentation.

And also I need to get the amplitude and phase out of it.
IIRC the amplitude is calculated like this `(realImg.pow(2) + imagImg.pow(2)).sqrt()`

How do I get the phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phase angle can be calulated using

`CImg<float> PhaseAngle = imagImage.get_atan2(realImg)`